# Python: replace multiple column values based on values present in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

good morning.

I am trying to replace multiple column values based on values present in other columns. I am able to do this in R but I dont understand how I can do the same with python. I tried using np.where() and df.loc approach but it only allows me to handle single column. The data is a result of one hot encoding, so the dataframe contains id, but then code columns are just 0s, and 1s. Since this data was one hot encoded we can have many code columns, but the only ones that need replacement are code3, and code4

Example Input

| id | code1 | code3 | code4 | code 5 | code..n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| CDE | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| EFG | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

**I want to accomplish the following**

Per row if there are any 1s in any other columns besides code3, and code4 then replace the 1s in the code3, and code4 column with 0s

Example Output

| id | code1 | code3 | code4 | code 5 | code..n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| CDE | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| EFG | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
c = ['code3', 'code4']
df.loc[df.drop(c, axis=1).eq(1).any(1), c] = 0
```

---

```
    id  code1  code3  code4  code 5  code..n
0  ABC      1      0      0       1        1
1  CDE      0      0      0       0        1
2  EFG      1      0      0       0        1
```

Comment: lovely..........

Comment: wow that is amazing! thank you Shubham Sharma! I am trying to understand why it works. We look at our df, drop values in code3, and code4 if anyone of those is equal to 0? is that correct? thank you!

Comment: @HarisJaved `drop` removes the `code3 and code4` columns then we use `.eq(1)` to create a boolean condition, then we use `any(1)` to reduce the boolean condition along column axis to check whether any other columns have `1` in the same row.

Comment: thank you so much Shubham! that makes sense